# Google Maps API change "disableDefaultUI" after initializise

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'm working with the Google Maps API and I want to show the controls by jQuery button click function.

I hide the controls at initializing with:

```
disableDefaultUI: true
```

but I didn't found a solution to show the controls later via a jQuery function.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Solution is:

```
    map.setOptions({
      disableDefaultUI: false
    });
```

Sry... maybe it helps someone else